# Google maps api setting markers reserved word

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps api for pulling in a map into a phonegap app. The map works well, but I am trying to set custom markers and are following this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons

Where you set the image the code is using a "anchor" setting. That is a reserved word in javascript and if it is left in the code, the javascript fails.

How would I get around this?

```
var image = {
url: 'images/beachflag.png',
// This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
// The origin for this image is 0,0.
origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
// The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since when is anchor a reserved word? Secondly, if you are using reserved words as keys in objects, just put them in quotes like

```
{
'anchor': new google.maps.Point(0,32)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't think you need to downgrade my answer. As in my ide placing anchor shows as a reserved word. I am trying to figure out if it jquery or jquery mobile. And leaving it in the code stops it from running.

Comment: No IDE needed - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words